# Получить максимальное число из колонки

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть код для получения максимального числа из колонки num в БД

```
$loginMax = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(num) FROM product WHERE login = 
'" . $client . "'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
$numMax = mysqli_fetch_array($loginMax, MYSQLI_NUM);
$numSum = $numMax[0] + 1;
echo $numSum;
mysqli_free_result($numMax);
```

Работает нормально но на СЛЕДУЮЩИЙ день опять считает с 1.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, что Вы подразумеваете под фразой *на СЛЕДУЮЩИЙ день опять считает с 1*

Comment: Ну до минут не скажу)) но если в течении дня заказы считает нормально, прибавляя к полученному числу  +1, то на утро опять заказ номер 1.

Comment: в коде ошибки нет. 1 может быть если `login` не найден, т.е. если `login` не найден, то `SELECT MAX(num) ...` вернет `null`, `$numMax[0]` будет равен `null`, а `null + 1 = 1;`

Comment: Надо проверить.

Comment: Если логин был бы null то вылезла ошибка

    `$client = $_POST['client'];//Клиент

     $loginMax = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(num) FROM product WHERE login = '" . 
     $client . "'") or die(mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: Дело не во времени вообще оказалось, если удалить заказы из БД и оставить с номером 1, то он почему то не видит его и считает 0+1

Comment: Понял в чем дело, он показывает максимальное число из логина, а нужно из колонки num

Comment: ну как бы да) у Вас же есть условие `WHERE login = '" . $client . "'`

Comment: *Если логин был бы null то вылезла ошибка ...* - читайте внимательнее, было написано *... если login не найден ...* ( если `$client` не найден в таблице). Никакой ошибки в данном случае не было бы, т.к. запрос вернул бы `null`

Comment: Дополнительно: вставлять необработанные данные из $_POST и т.п. (`$client = $_POST['client'];`) сразу в запрос неправильно, используйте подготовленные выражения.

Comment: @Alex можно пример грамотного подготовленного выражения?

Comment: документация с примерами [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: @Alex ну я так тоже могу.

Comment: что именно из документации Вам непонятно ? там в т.ч. есть и примеры

Comment: В таком варианте
   `$loginMax = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(num) FROM product")`
что подгатавливать то?

Comment: пожалуйста, будьте [внимательнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/970629/#comment1628623_970629)

Answer (score 0):

В коде не правильно прописан запрос, я выбирал максимальное число из клиента, а нужно из колонки num.

```
$loginMax = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(num) FROM product") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: прекрасная практика обработки ошибок с `die` и выкатыванием текста запроса пользователю, браво!

Comment: Исправился, понял.